# How to exclude jQuery from a certain webpack bundles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'am exploring an opportunity to exclude jQuery from a certain webpack bundles. For example, my webpack.config.js has two entry points

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index/index': [ 'babel-polyfill', './resources/assets/modules/index/index', ],
        'auth/index': [ 'babel-polyfill', './resources/assets/modules/auth/index', ],
    },
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default',],
        }),
        ...
    ],
}
```

In bundle analyzer I can see, that jQuery is included in both `auth/index` and `index/index` bundle. But actually, I need jQuery only in `index/index` module. How can I do it?

PS webpack version 3

Comment: which version of webpack?

Comment: @MatheusSilva webpack 3